# My app some times hangs

Tags: android

On my main launch page I have a zoom animation on items in a gridview. I notice that when I navigate through my UI and I intend going back to my home page. that the UI some times freezes and crashes.  I dont have an idea of what could cause this. Cause I am sure that there is no error in the code. 
I have pasted the stack trace below

```
10-06 07:19:42.624: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 14K, 42% free 4021K/6919K, external 8275K/8764K, paused 146ms
10-06 07:19:42.864: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.287MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:42.885: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 61K, 43% free 3960K/6919K, external 8245K/8764K, paused 96ms
10-06 07:19:43.034: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 43% free 3957K/6919K, external 8245K/8764K, paused 143ms
10-06 07:19:43.254: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.208MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:43.254: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9K, 43% free 3947K/6919K, external 8177K/8764K, paused 81ms
10-06 07:19:43.474: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 13K, 44% free 3934K/6919K, external 8159K/8764K, paused 122ms
10-06 07:19:43.674: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.236MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:43.674: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 44% free 3934K/6919K, external 8219K/8764K, paused 80ms
10-06 07:19:43.974: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 44% free 3934K/6919K, external 8219K/8764K, paused 217ms
10-06 07:19:44.295: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.265MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:44.295: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 44% free 3934K/6919K, external 8250K/8764K, paused 150ms
10-06 07:19:44.604: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 44% free 3934K/6919K, external 8250K/8764K, paused 215ms
10-06 07:19:44.884: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.225MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:44.884: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11K, 44% free 3923K/6919K, external 8219K/8764K, paused 118ms
10-06 07:19:45.164: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 44% free 3922K/6919K, external 8219K/8764K, paused 176ms
10-06 07:19:45.405: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.720MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:45.414: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 44% free 3921K/6919K, external 8728K/8764K, paused 95ms
10-06 07:19:47.614: W/KeyCharacterMap(436): No keyboard for id -1
10-06 07:19:47.624: W/KeyCharacterMap(436): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-06 07:19:47.924: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 59K, 43% free 3960K/6919K, external 8266K/8764K, paused 149ms
10-06 07:19:48.134: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 0K, 43% free 3960K/6919K, external 8266K/8764K, paused 146ms
10-06 07:19:48.314: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.758MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:48.314: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11K, 43% free 3949K/6919K, external 8739K/10787K, paused 96ms
10-06 07:19:48.864: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 43% free 3950K/6919K, external 8739K/10787K, paused 133ms
10-06 07:19:49.074: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.778MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:49.074: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 43% free 3950K/6919K, external 8758K/10787K, paused 80ms
10-06 07:19:49.394: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 43% free 3950K/6919K, external 8758K/10787K, paused 244ms
10-06 07:19:49.744: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.786MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:49.754: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 43% free 3950K/6919K, external 8766K/10787K, paused 171ms
10-06 07:19:50.024: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 43% free 3950K/6919K, external 8746K/10787K, paused 181ms
10-06 07:19:50.244: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.759MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:50.244: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 43% free 3950K/6919K, external 8739K/10787K, paused 134ms
10-06 07:19:53.534: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 15K, 43% free 3996K/6919K, external 8693K/10727K, paused 263ms
10-06 07:19:53.684: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.766MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:19:53.694: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1K, 43% free 3995K/6919K, external 8702K/10727K, paused 49ms
10-06 07:21:14.895: W/KeyCharacterMap(436): No keyboard for id -1
10-06 07:21:14.895: W/KeyCharacterMap(436): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
10-06 07:21:15.217: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 301K, 39% free 4473K/7303K, external 8702K/10727K, paused 195ms
10-06 07:21:15.884: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 17.286MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:15.884: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6K, 39% free 4466K/7303K, external 8762K/10727K, paused 287ms
10-06 07:21:16.174: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 191K, 42% free 4275K/7303K, external 8762K/10727K, paused 135ms
10-06 07:21:16.444: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 17.106MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:16.444: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3K, 42% free 4272K/7303K, external 8772K/10727K, paused 121ms
10-06 07:21:16.704: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 0K, 42% free 4272K/7303K, external 8772K/10727K, paused 172ms
10-06 07:21:16.965: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.934MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:16.965: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 182K, 45% free 4089K/7303K, external 8780K/10727K, paused 123ms
10-06 07:21:17.164: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4089K/7303K, external 8780K/10727K, paused 124ms
10-06 07:21:17.334: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.944MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:17.334: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4089K/7303K, external 8789K/10727K, paused 63ms
10-06 07:21:17.514: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4089K/7303K, external 8789K/10727K, paused 102ms
10-06 07:21:17.624: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.369MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:17.624: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3K, 45% free 4085K/7303K, external 8204K/10245K, paused 65ms
10-06 07:21:17.734: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4085K/7303K, external 8204K/10245K, paused 105ms
10-06 07:21:17.894: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.379MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:17.894: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4085K/7303K, external 8214K/10245K, paused 50ms
10-06 07:21:18.214: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8214K/10245K, paused 243ms
10-06 07:21:18.555: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.438MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:18.555: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8274K/10245K, paused 156ms
10-06 07:21:18.824: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8274K/10245K, paused 181ms
10-06 07:21:19.044: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.425MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:19.044: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4085K/7303K, external 8262K/10245K, paused 135ms
10-06 07:21:19.244: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4085K/7303K, external 8262K/10245K, paused 171ms
10-06 07:21:19.794: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.434MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:19.804: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4085K/7303K, external 8271K/10245K, paused 427ms
10-06 07:21:20.014: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8271K/10245K, paused 138ms
10-06 07:21:20.234: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.445MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:20.234: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8282K/10245K, paused 85ms
10-06 07:21:20.434: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8282K/10245K, paused 129ms
10-06 07:21:20.584: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.429MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:20.584: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8265K/10245K, paused 87ms
10-06 07:21:20.724: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8265K/10245K, paused 127ms
10-06 07:21:20.924: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.916MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:20.934: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8763K/10245K, paused 80ms
10-06 07:21:21.334: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8753K/10245K, paused 166ms
10-06 07:21:21.504: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.922MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:21.504: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8771K/10245K, paused 64ms
10-06 07:21:21.924: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8771K/10245K, paused 339ms
10-06 07:21:22.424: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.932MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:22.424: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8780K/10245K, paused 176ms
10-06 07:21:22.824: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8780K/10245K, paused 315ms
10-06 07:21:23.034: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.428MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:23.044: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8264K/10245K, paused 132ms
10-06 07:21:23.254: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8255K/10245K, paused 185ms
10-06 07:21:23.314: I/dalvikvm(436): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-06 07:21:23.514: I/dalvikvm(436): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-06 07:21:23.795: I/dalvikvm-heap(436): Clamp target GC heap from 16.916MB to 16.000MB
10-06 07:21:23.795: D/dalvikvm(436): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 45% free 4086K/7303K, external 8763K/10245K, paused 259ms
```

My code is below:

```
package com.example.rhemahealthcare;

import java.util.List;


import com.actionbarsherlock.R;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.example.customadapters.GridImageAdapter;
import com.example.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.dbobject.DrugStallModel;
import com.example.dbobject.HospitalModel;
import com.example.dbobject.PatientModel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.SubMenu;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    static final String[] menuString = new String[] { "Find Hospital","Drug Stalls","Emergency Calls","Medical Student","Nafdac","Health Gossip" };
    //create the aleert dialog manager here
        AlertDialogManager alert= new AlertDialogManager();

        DatabaseHelper dbhelper = null;

        Resources resource = null;

         public static int THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock;

         Context context = null;

        // LinearLayout hint = null,hint1 = null;


    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView( com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.layout.homeactivity);
         // loadApps();
            resource = getResources();

            context = HomeActivity.this;

            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

          //  hint = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sim);
          // hint1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(com.actionbarsherlock.R.id.hint1);

            dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


            GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(new GridImageAdapter(HomeActivity.this,menuString,resource));

            //adding the individual onClick event on the items in the grid
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //TextView v =  ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.griditemText));
                    //String textValue = v.getText().toString();

                    String selectMenutext = (String) ((TextView) view.findViewById( com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.griditemText)).getText();

                    if(selectMenutext.equals("Find Hospital")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,HospitalsInRegion.class);
                        startActivity(intent);                      
                    }

                    else if(selectMenutext.equals("Drug Stalls")){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,DrugStallsInRegionActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);                      
                    }

                    else if(selectMenutext.equals("Health Gossip")){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,PreHealthGossipActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else if(selectMenutext.equals("Medical Student")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,MedicalStudentActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);                      
                    }

                    else if(selectMenutext.equals("Emergency Calls")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,PreEmergencyActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else if(selectMenutext.equals("Nafdac")){
                        Intent intent  = new Intent(context,NafdacActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }

            });
        }


       @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){             

           MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.menu.homemenu, menu);

            return true;          
        }



       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

           int itemID = item.getItemId();

           switch(itemID){

           //This is going to work for the action bar back button
           case android.R.id.home:
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
               break;


           case com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.lasthospital:
               this.displayLastHospitalVisited();
               break;

           case com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.lastpharmacy:
               this.displayLastDrugStallVisited();
               break;

           case com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.medicalcard:
               this.displayMedicalCard();
               break;

           case com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.settings:
               this.displayAppSettings();
               break;

           case com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.help:
               this.displayHelp();
               break;

           case com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.about:
               this.displayAbout();
               break;

           case com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.id.maplocation:
               this.displayMapLocation();
               break;

           default:
            break;

           }

          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   
       }


       //This method is going to be used too display the health Gossip page
       private void displayMapLocation(){
           //Intent intent = new Intent(context,HealthGossipActivity.class);
           //startActivity(intent);
       }


       //This method is goign to be used to display the last hospital visited by the patient
       private void displayLastHospitalVisited(){

           //we would have to check the database and see if the user as visited a hospital

           if(this.ReturnHospitalName() == null){
               String errormsg = resource.getString(com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.string.notvisitedHospital);
               Toast.makeText(context, errormsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           else{
               //Toast.makeText(context,"Last hospital selected ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Intent intent = new Intent(context,HospitalMenuActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       }

       //This method is going to be used to display the last phamercitical firm visited
       private void displayLastDrugStallVisited(){

           //we would have to check the database and see if the user as visited a drug stall 

           if(this.ReturnDrugStallName() == null){
               String errormsg = resource.getString(com.example.rhemahealthcare.R.string.notvisiteddrugstall);
               Toast.makeText(context, errormsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           else{
               Intent intent = new Intent(context,DrugStallMenuActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       }

       //This method is going to be used to display settings
       private void displayAppSettings(){
           Intent intent = new Intent(context,SettingsActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }


       //This method is going to display the Help Activity
       private void displayHelp(){

           Intent intent = new Intent(context,HelpActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }

       private void displayAbout(){

           Intent intent = new Intent(context,AboutActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }

       //This method is going to display the patient medical card
       private void displayMedicalCard(){

          PatientModel patient = dbhelper.ReturnPatientDetails(1);
          Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,PatientMedicalCardActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("phone",patient.getPhone());
          intent.putExtra("email",patient.getEmail());
          startActivity(intent);

       }


       //We are going to collect the drug stall name from the database
        private DrugStallModel ReturnDrugStallName(){
            String drugstallname= new String();

            DrugStallModel drugstall = this.dbhelper.ReturnLastVisitedDrugStall(1);

            return drugstall;
        }


        //We would collect the name of the hospital from the database
        private HospitalModel ReturnHospitalName(){
            String hospitalName = new String();

            HospitalModel hospital = this.dbhelper.ReturnLastVisitedHospitalDetails(1);

            return hospital;
        }


      }
```

The xml of my layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lineargrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hintlinearrect"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hint" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hintText"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hint1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hintlinearrect"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hint" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nointernet"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/detailsicon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        style="@style/gridViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_wave_scale"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

</LinearLayout>



<gridLayoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:rowDelay="75%"
        android:columnDelay="0%"
        android:directionPriority="none"
        android:animation="@anim/wave_scale" />
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have pasted my code there. The crash happens mostly when I naviagate back to this activity which is the home activity that the user see when he launches the application. Though it does not happen always. It happens on a very few occasion. But am feeling it cos of the animation possibly it may not perform too well on the emulator.

Comment: It just  surpises me that it works very well most times. could it be an emulator thing.

Comment: It looks like you're exceeding the heap limit.  I'm not sure how to set the heap size, but I would suspect that the real issue is you're trying to allocate something very large and don't realize it.

Comment: ok yeah that is the problem though. but I dont know what it could be

Comment: @Peri Hartman could multiple activity in the stack cause an heap size memory error.

Comment: Cause I notice that this problem arises when I have gone through many activities in my application. cos I have not yet added the finish() method between activities. could it be mulitple activities in stack exceeding lot of memory usage.

Comment: Yeah I have a clearer problem of what is happening now. I have put the application to a simple test. When I go back and front. at one stage the application slow down when it tries to display this homeactivity. Could it be that the animation there is consuming lot of memory

Comment: You'll have to determine that :)  I'm answering as a comment rather than an Answer because I don't know the answer.  Just pointing out the evident culprit.  I'm sure there's a way to monitor memory usage and you can probably pinpoint what action is causing the big gulp.  I also suggest thinking about your algorithm and whether you are doing something like animating a high res image where you might be able to do with a lower res image and maybe coarser animation stages.

Comment: Ok bro tanks alot @PeriHartman

Comment: Well the animation I am using is the wave scale in the Api demo